# jQuery Mobile transitions and AJAX Polling on a MasterPage

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, jquery-mobile, ajax-polling

I am trying to use AJAX polling with jQuery to update a span element on a razor MasterPage in ASP.NET MVC3. The page uses the jQuery Mobile 1.0 framework that adorns simple view changes (like navigating from /home to /about) with some sort of "transition" animation.

This is the Javascript code that does the polling, while the "unreadBubble" span is located in the body - both are defined in the MasterPage!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).bind("pageinit", function poll() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.ajax({ url: "/Notification/GetUnreadNotificationsCount", 
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                    $('#unreadBubble').text(data.UnreadCount);
                    poll();
                } 
            });
    }, 1000);
});
```

So, imagine I have a HomeController and a NotificationController that both use the MasterPage and provide an Index view. The AJAX polling works on both views and updates the span every second as expected. As soon as I navigate from one view to another though, the span gets re-initialized with its default value from the MasterPage (empty) and doesn't update anymore. Interestingly the async GetUnreadNotificationsCount method is still called on the NotificationsController repeatedly - the span just doesn't update. I also tried to alert the span tag in JS and it wasn't null or something.

According to the [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html), jQuery Mobile also loads new pages with AJAX to insert this fancy "SWOOSH" transition animation. This seems to somehow disturb the JS/DOM initialization.

Do you have any idea how to resolve this? Should I bind to another event or can I somehow force the span tag to update?

**Solution**: It was a caching problem! The following did the trick:
Add *class="command-no-cache"* to your page div add the following JavaScript to the MasterPage:

```
$(":jqmData(role=page)").live('pagehide', function (event, ui) {
if ($(this).children("div[data-role*='content']").is(".command-no-cache"))
    $(this).remove();
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the pagebeforeshow to actually bind the event, and pagehide to remove the event.

Did you try that instead of initializing only once in the pageinit event?

UPDATE: some code for example,

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var timer = null;
 $(":jqmData(role=page)").bind("pagebeforeshow", function() {
     timer = setTimeout(function() {
               $.ajax({ url: "/Notification/GetUnreadNotificationsCount", 
                  dataType: "json",
                  success: function (data) {
                     $('#unreadBubble').text(data.UnreadCount);
                  } 
               });
             }, 1000);
 }); 
 $(":jqmData(role=page)").bind("pagehide", function() {
     if (timer != null){
          clearTimeout(timer);
          timer = null;
     }
 });
</script>
```

Also corrected some other ""mistypes" along the way, have a look and compare to your code!

Hope this helps

Comment: On which element do I have to (un)bind these events? Would you mind posting some example code?

Comment: Unfortunately, GetUnreadNotificationsCount no longer gets called. I also tried a simple selector by Id instead of ":jqmData(data-role=page)" but still no joy.

Comment: oh,sorry, maybe try with `$("div:jqmData(role='page')")`

Comment: Nope, it doesn't even work if I try to bind it using $('#mypage'). The markup of the page is <div id="mypage" data-role="page">. Thanks for your effort by the way!

Comment: Awww, I finally got it - it was a caching problem! I added the solution to my question. Since you got my on the right track with the pagehide event, I marked your reply as answer.